# How to initialise a nested object which is being defined in OnInit? Angular2

Tags: angular, object, nested

So I keep getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'otherDocumentaryEvidence' of undefined". I understand I need to initialise this object somehow but I am unsure of the process of this. My understanding is that the object gets defined during the ngOnInit stage from a template service

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._templateService
        .getTemplateSnapshot(this.template)
        .responseData()
        .subscribe(templateSnapStream => {
            return this.shareCase = templateSnapStream.result;
        })
}
```

My object looks like this

```
export class ShareCase {
    shareCaseReason?: string;
    caseDetails?: ICasedeit;
    involvedPersonsAndOrganisations?: IInvolved;
    policeOfficer?: IPolice;
    incidents?: IIncident;
    offences?: IOffence;
    suspect?: ISuspectDetails
    witnessStatements?: IStatements;
    interviewNotes?: IIncident;
    notebookEntries?: INotebook;
    victims?: IVictim;
    witnesses?: IWitness;
    physicalEvidence?: IEvidence;
    otherDocumentaryEvidence?: IDocEvidence;
}
```

In my component code I initialise both the Share Case object and the otherDocumentaryEvidence object in the constructor like so:

```
 this.shareCase = new ShareCase();
 this.shareCase.otherDocumentaryEvidence = new IDocEvidence();
```

But I still get the same error? I am unsure of why this is. The line in my template which calls this object also looks like this

```
 <div *ngIf='shareCase && shareCase.case.otherDocumentaryEvidence && shareCase.case.otherDocumentaryEvidence.length > 0'>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an additional check in your `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf='shareCase && 
            shareCase.case && 
            shareCase.case.otherDocumentaryEvidence && 
            shareCase.case.otherDocumentaryEvidence.length > 0'>
```

You are missing `shareCase.case` check

Comment: Magic! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the question mark for null/undefined check.

```
<div *ngIf='shareCase && shareCase.case?.otherDocumentaryEvidence && shareCase.case?.otherDocumentaryEvidence.length > 0'>
```